# How to apply Node.js secuirty updates?

Tags: node.js, security, meteor, patch

How to apply node.js security patches?
Is there a specific process to apply security patches when using meteor js on ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. May I suggest you put this question on https://askubuntu.com ? Contributors there probably have good answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running meteor in production mode, it is run as a (pure) node.js app. So the short answer to your question is to just update node (depending on how you installed it; probably `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install nodejs -y`).

There are a variety of tools you can use to deploy a meteor app (e.g. [meteor-up](http://meteor-up.com/)), but all of them have essentially the same two steps, which are easy enough to do yourself:

1. Bundle your meteor app into a node.js app
    
   `meteor build ../my-build-output-folder --server https://my.production.site.url --architecture os.linux.x86_64`

   This will create a `meteor-server.tar.gz` file in the folder you specified, containing the node.js app. The process is then (as per the `README` file that is included in the bundle):

   1. Transfer the `meteor-server.tar.gz` file to your server
   2. `tar -zxvf meteor-server.tar.gz` to extract the node application
   3. The included `README` file tells you the rest :

README:

```
This is a Meteor application bundle. It has only one external dependency:
Node.js v8.11.4. To run the application:

  $ (cd programs/server && npm install)
  $ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'
  $ export ROOT_URL='http://example.com'
  $ export MAIL_URL='smtp://user:password@mailhost:port/'
  $ node main.js

Use the PORT environment variable to set the port where the
application will listen. The default is 80, but that will require
root on most systems.
```

2. Set up a system to survive restarts e.g. [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) , [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) , or [docker](https://www.docker.com/)